# Jadclipse is not working in Eclipse Kepler SR2

Tags: java, eclipse-kepler, jad

Here is what I did:

- Installed Jadclipse plugin for Eclipse 4.*
- Ran Eclipse with -clean
- Set the editor for "Class without source" to "Class decompiler viewer" (there were no explicit jad decompiler or the like)
- Opened a .class file with "Class decompiler viewer"

It still says that "Source not found" and I get the same old...

What could have gone wrong?

If you can point me to a wiki page or something that would be fine since the plugin's wiki is **empty** and googling for it did not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also installed JadClipse for Eclipse 4.x 4.0.0. I'm using Kepler SR1.

The .class file I'd previously opened still remained "Source not found" so I right clicked on the class in the Project Explorer and selected Open Class With > Jad (Ctrl_Shift-V)

That worked for me. The class file was in a jar referenced in one of my eclipse projects.

If you didn't get the Open Class With > Jad menu then perhaps you should try uninstalling and re-installing?

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Kepler SR2 has two types of options:
1. *.class
2. *.class without source.

Make sure you associate both of them with jad decompiler.

go to preferences --> Editors --> File associations, image attached.